# json parsing showing url and title in textview

Tags: php, android, json, url

I've got a little thing with json / android parsing.

I'm parsing data from my database to android textview with json.

But some how it's also showing the url and title.

Is there a way to hide this or modify the code so that it isn't showing?

http://www.wvvzondag2.nl/android/leesverslag.php{"introtext":"my value from the database"}

I would like to see that it is showing my value from the database, so with out the url and brackets.

this is the code I'm using.

```
package wvv.zondag.app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Leesverslag extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView txt;

public static final String KEY_121 = "http://www.wvvzondag2.nl/android/leesverslag.php"; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.leesverslag);
    LinearLayout mLinearlayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linear);
        txt = new TextView(this);
        txt.setText("Connecting..."); 
        mLinearlayout.addView(txt);

        Runnable postRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(getServerData(KEY_121))); 

            }
        };
        txt.post(postRunnable);
}

private String getServerData(String returnString) {
   InputStream is = null;

   String result = "";
    //Value from last activity for database
   String titelhoofd = getIntent().getStringExtra("titelverslag");
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("titel",titelhoofd));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    json_data.getString("introtext");
                    //Get an output to the screen
                    returnString += jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
            }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return returnString; 
}    

}
```

Does anybody know how the fix the problem ?

Kind regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable

```
String strData = "";
```

and then use

```
//parse json data
try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                //Get an output to the screen
                strData += json_data.getString("introtext"); 
        }
}catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
return strData ;
```